# Several problems regarding rigging

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting, pose-mode

I downloaded a mesh from a website and started rigging it, but I'm having a lot of trouble making it work.

The first issue is that in Pose Mode I can't reset the pose to the Rest Position. After ALT+G/R/S'ing everyting I can see there is a difference between the bones in Edit and Pose mode.

The second problem is that when I go to Object mode, right click the mesh, shift+right click the rig, hit ctrl+P and select "With Automatic Weights", I get the message "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" and then the mesh looks weird.

I read somewhere that the second problem is due to the Rest and Pose Position not being the same, but I'm not sure. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It's because the mesh is non-manifold.

Comment: @Leander Can you elaborate? A quick google search told me it's "geometry which cannot exist in the real world". How did you figure that out, why is it a problem, and is there anything I can do about it, or should i search for another mesh?

Comment: There is a question about [non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/30849) already, which explains it well. The foot and finger nails have non-manifold geometry, which doesn't work with the automatic weighting. You can separate them and paint them manually, without them, the automatic weighting works as expected. The problem with the strange posing of the legs originates from the ik constraint. With your setup the pole Angle has to be *90°*-ish.

Comment: @Leander I can live without the nails. What would the easiest way to get rid of them be? Regarding the other thing, I just have to click on my Lower Leg bone, go to Bone Constraints and set Pole Angle to 90, right?